# Prove this inequality for sufficiently large $n$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

Prove that the above inequality holds for sufficiently large $n$:

$$\pi(2n) - \frac{3}{2} \pi(n) \ge O\left(\frac{\ln n}{(\ln \ln n )^2}\right)$$

$\ln n$ denotes to natural logarithm and $\pi(n)$ is prime counting function.

Comment: Which facts are allowed to use in the proof? I expect it is quite easy, if we use an approximaton $\pi(n)\simeq \frac{n}{\ln n}$. For instance, for $n\ge 55$ holds
$\frac n{\ln n+2}<\pi(n)<\frac n{\ln n-4}$ (see, Rosser B., Proc. London Math. Soc, 1939, v.45(2), p. 21-44).